# Stream bash/terminal/console output to website/api

Tags: bash, file-io, stream, streaming, wget

How I can stream the "log" (for example) to a website which saves this log?

For example I have a web interface which manages a lot of rendering processes on a lot of Amazon EC2 servers.

Now I want to let them stream the console output to the website, so that I can save this output as a log of the server.

Something like:

```
echo "do something small" > https://api.example.org/server/123/log 2>&1
```

Or like

```
wget stream `echo "something dynamic" 2>&1` https://api.example.org/server/123/log
```

As fallback I could use something like:

```
echo "do something local" > /var/log/upload.log 2>&1
curl -F "file=@/var/log/upload.log;filename=upload.log" https://api.example.org/server/123/log
```

But I want to stream directly so that everybody can read it directly.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ssh, you could pipe it over ssh:

```
echo hi | ssh server 'cat - >>/tmp/log'
```

But it wouldn't be terribly graceful if the connection dies.

Comment: Hmm yes but a nice idea. Like it ^^ But I think we can stream videos from a website to a tv so we should be able to stream data from computer to webserver :)